# Why is xfs filesystem type greyed out in Gparted?

Tags: 13.10, gparted, xfs

I have a large hd that only 1/2 of it is an ext4 for /home. I am trying to make another partition using the XFS filesystem but its greyed out in Gparted. From what I have read here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XFS its already installed and loaded in the kernel module.

Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because as gparted says in view -> Filesystem Support, it needs the xfsprogs package to be installed.

Comment: Thanks, though it was installed properly, Gparted shows exactly what package is needed.